# Create "Photo App" using FlipView, ScrollViewer and Manipulation on Universal App

Tags: zooming, scrollviewer, win-universal-app, flipview

I currently working on a project that create an app just like Photo App on Windows 8.1

Some different:

- Each item contain 2 image side by side (I use Grid with 2 Column)

Expecting behaviors:

1. Swipe through item (which is Grid contain 2 image side by side)
2. Zoom in a specific item
3. Prevent Swiping when zooming
4. Automatically zoom to normal when zoom out too much

Worked:

1. Using FlipView with DataTemplate
2. Wrap the Grid with ScrollViewer, set ZoomMode to Enable

For 3 and 4, here is what i have so far
3:

First, get the ScrollViewer of the FlipView

```
MainFlipViewScrollViewer = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ScrollViewer>(MainFlipView);
```

Then, get the ScrollViewer INSIDE the datatemplate and register for ViewChanged event

```
var flipViewItem = MainFlipView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(MainFlipView.SelectedIndex);
var scrollViewItem = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ScrollViewer>(flipViewItem);
scrollViewItem.ViewChanged += scrollViewItem_ViewChanged;
```

in the ViewChanged Event Handler, check if ZoomFactor is larger normal to disable the ScrollViewer of FlipView, and smaller than normal to reset to normal

```
void scrollViewItem_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    float zoomF = ((ScrollViewer)sender).ZoomFactor;
    if (zoomF > 1.0f)
    {
        MainFlipViewScrollViewer.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ((ScrollViewer)sender).ZoomToFactor(1.0f);
        MainFlipViewScrollViewer.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I just zoom out a little bit, the Image not response to touch (it doesn't hang)

And all of this affect the first item only. When I swipe to next item, I can zoom in, zoom out, the scrollViewItem_ViewChanged event does not fire

PS: the code for FindFirstElementInVisualTree

```
private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parentElement != null)
        {
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
            if (count == 0)
                return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

                if (child != null && child is T)
                    return (T)child;
                else
                {
                    var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I guess that FlipView have 4 item in a row, then repeat them for hundred item in ItemsSource

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".